# How to shutdown a GenericKeyedObjectPool safely?

Tags: java, apache-commons, pooling, apache-commons-pool

I have a [`GenericKeyedObjectPool`](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html) in my application.
I can close it with the `close` method but how should I wait for the clients to return (and the pool destroys) every borrowed object to the pool?

I need something like [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper for the `GenericKeyedObjectPool` which has the required `awaitTermination` method. You can check the `close` and the `returnObject` calls and decrement a latch if the pool is closed and every object was returned (= the total number of instances current borrowed from this pool is zero).

```
public final class ListenablePool<K, V> {

    private final GenericKeyedObjectPool<K, V> delegate;

    private final CountDownLatch closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean();

    public ListenablePool(final KeyedPoolableObjectFactory<K, V> factory) {
        this.delegate = new GenericKeyedObjectPool<K, V>(factory);
    }

    public V borrowObject(final K key) throws Exception {
        return delegate.borrowObject(key);
    }

    public void returnObject(final K key, final V obj) throws Exception {
        try {
            delegate.returnObject(key, obj);
        } finally {
            countDownIfRequired();
        }
    }

    private void countDownIfRequired() {
        if (closed.get() && delegate.getNumActive() == 0) {
            closeLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

    public void close() throws Exception {
        try {
            delegate.close();
        } finally {
            closed.set(true);
            countDownIfRequired();
        }
    }

    public void awaitTermination() throws InterruptedException {
        closeLatch.await();
    }

    public void awaitTermination(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) 
            throws InterruptedException {
        closeLatch.await(timeout, unit);
    }

    public int getNumActive() {
        return delegate.getNumActive();
    }

    // other delegate methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe just closing it, without waiting for all objects to be returned.

From the docs of [GenericKeyedObjectPool.html#close()](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html#close%28%29):

> Closes the pool. Once the pool is closed, borrowObject() will fail
>   with IllegalStateException, but returnObject(Object) and
>   invalidateObject(Object) will continue to work, with returned objects
>   destroyed on return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The pooled objects are database/network connections, so it's more friendly for the remote systems to close them if it's possible. Anyway, it made me think that I might not want to wait forever for the object which might never be returned.